# Is Cantor set is compact with respect to lower limit Topology on $R$?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

Is Cantor set is compact with respect to lower limit Topology on $R$?
I know Cantor set is compact with respect to usual topology.
But I think it's not compact in lower limit Topology..
Because I think we can write Cantor set as [0,$a_1$) union [$a_1$,$a_2$)...union 1.
But I am not able to write it explicitly..
I am not able to find it's cover that will have infinite subcover.
Please give me some hint..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $R$ refers to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., the set of real numbers. The answer is no, the Cantor set is not compact with respect to the lower limit topology $\tau$. This follows from the fact that every compact subset of $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ must be countable, while the Cantor set itself is uncountable.

Comment: I am unable to understand why every compact subset with lower limit Topology on Real line must be countable? Can you give me some more detail to understand this part..

Comment: It is fairly well explained on wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology But it is also not too difficult to prove, so I recommend that you try that first.

Answer (score 1):

In the Sorgenfrey Line (also called the lower-limit topology), the family $\{[0,x): 0<x<1\}\cup \{[1,2)\}$ is an open cover of the Cantor set with no finite sub-cover